# Public transport from Treviso airport to Lavarone

Tags: public-transport, airport-transfer, italy, tsf

We are planning a skiing trip in Lavarone Italy. We are going to land at Treviso Airport however we don't know if there is any public transport available. Any idea where we can find any information?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Take bus line 6 from Treviso Airport to Treviso Centrale. Zooming in on [Google Maps](http://goo.gl/maps/u1EvL) shows a number of bus stops outside the airport. I'm not sure exactly where the terminal is, but there is surely a bus stop. Buses are operated by [ACTT](http://www.actt.it/) and pass quite frequently. On [this page](http://www.actt.it/orari-linee) you can find the timetable for *feriale* (working days) and *festivi* (holidays).
2. Take a train from Treviso Centrale to Trento. You will need a number of changes. [This travel planner](http://hafas.bene-system.com/bin/query.exe/en?L=b-rail) may be of use, but I don't know if it's complete. The journey will take 3–4 hours depending on the connection. Connections may be via Vicenza and Verona, via Venezia and Verona, or via Cittadella. The latter connection is probably cheaper, because it uses only regional trains, whereas the connections via Vicenza/Venezia and Verona use fast trains with compulsory reservations. I don't know if you can buy the ticket all the way via Trento directly at the Treviso railway station, but I would guess this is possible.
3. Take bus line 303 from Trento to Lavarone. [Google Transit](http://goo.gl/maps/uZRjv) has connections for the local bus company, [TTE Sercizio](http://www.ttesercizio.it/). This connection normally takes 1 hour 26 minutes.

There may be another route, e.g. with the slower but possibly more scenic route with a train to Calceranica, which lies closer to Lavarone than Trento does. However, I'm a bit confused by the bus connection between Calceranica and Lavarone, so the alternative I described above may be a safer bet.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. However It's still not 100% clear what we need to do. So if i understood correctly we need to get a train to Calceranita via line 6 (which one of the stations is at Calceranita ?) then we get a bus to trentino, is tat correct

Comment: @Jonny Sorry, I was confused myself. I hope it's more clear now.